# Change edit mfc control text from another

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi I have two dialog form on C++ MFC 2010 and I want change edit control on from1 by form2 .

How I can done it ?

Comment: Are both forms part of the same program?

Comment: Yes are both form part of the same program

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, you should NOT directly access controls of one form from another. This creates unneeded tight coupling between them, exposing internals of one form to another.

I suggest you implement a public setter that identifies the purpose rather than the control ID that might change without you knowing it.

In the target form:

```
public:
  void SetUserName(const char* name)
  {
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, name);
  }
```

And in the caller:

```
form1.SetUserName("new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`SetDlgItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493w3x6d.aspx).

```
form1.SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, "new text");
```